# Derivatives of delta

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate `E` by this equation. But I am not sure if I can obtain results with `numpy.diff` module. It exports 4 points only.

[image]

```py
from numpy import diff

x = [395.33, 472.12, 560.45, 652.72, 732.55]
y = [0.17, 0.22, 0.28, 0.34, 0.41]
E = diff(y) / diff(x)

print(E)
```

Output:

```py
[0.00065113 0.00067927 0.00065027 0.00087686]
```

Comment: 5 numbers give 4 differences, so the number 4 is to be expected. What you have done is a reasonable approximation, although `gradient` (in the answer below) uses a more sophisticated numerical differentiation algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that the derivative is computed only on the intermediates segments between successive points, thus having one less value than the number of points.

What you expect is unclear, do you want to compute the [`gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)?

```
import numpy as np

E = np.gradient(y, x)
```

Output:

```
array([0.00065113, 0.00066422, 0.00066508, 0.00077175, 0.00087686])
```

Differences between `diff` and `gradient`:

[image]

More complex example:

Observe how the green curve is exactly the derivative of each segment (=slope), while the gradient is smoother (depends on points before and after)

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, `diff` is computing the slope of the lines between successive points (derivative), which is probably what you want. `gradient` is a more complex calculation based on the second-order accurate central differences in the interior points (see the documentation). I'm adding a graph of the two